# Setting up rngd (randomness generator) on old computers

Tags: linux, random

The `rngd` program comes from package `rng-tools5` on Ubuntu/Debian.

---

```
# neofetch 
             ...-:::::-...                 root@dell-7577 
          .-MMMMMMMMMMMMMMM-.              -------------- 
      .-MMMM`..-:::::::-..`MMMM-.          OS: Linux Mint 21.1 x86_64 
    .:MMMM.:MMMMMMMMMMMMMMM:.MMMM:.        Host: Inspiron 7577 
   -MMM-M---MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM.MMM-       Kernel: 5.15.0-57-generic 
 `:MMM:MM`  :MMMM:....::-...-MMMM:MMM:`    Uptime: 32 mins 
 :MMM:MMM`  :MM:`  ``    ``  `:MMM:MMM:    Packages: 3489 (dpkg), 45 (flatpak), 11 (snap) 
.MMM.MMMM`  :MM.  -MM.  .MM-  `MMMM.MMM.   Shell: bash 5.1.16 
:MMM:MMMM`  :MM.  -MM-  .MM:  `MMMM-MMM:   Resolution: 1920x1080 
:MMM:MMMM`  :MM.  -MM-  .MM:  `MMMM:MMM:   DE: Cinnamon 5.6.5 
:MMM:MMMM`  :MM.  -MM-  .MM:  `MMMM-MMM:   WM: Mutter (Muffin) 
.MMM.MMMM`  :MM:--:MM:--:MM:  `MMMM.MMM.   WM Theme: Mint-Y-Dark-Aqua (Mint-Y) 
 :MMM:MMM-  `-MMMMMMMMMMMM-`  -MMM-MMM:    Theme: Mint-Y-Aqua [GTK2/3] 
  :MMM:MMM:`                `:MMM:MMM:     Icons: Mint-Y-Aqua [GTK2/3] 
   .MMM.MMMM:--------------:MMMM.MMM.      Terminal: gnome-terminal 
     '-MMMM.-MMMMMMMMMMMMMMM-.MMMM-'       CPU: Intel i7-7700HQ (8) @ 3.800GHz 
       '.-MMMM``--:::::--``MMMM-.'         GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile 
            '-MMMMMMMMMMMMM-'              GPU: Intel HD Graphics 630 
               ``-:::::-``                 Memory: 1158MiB / 31839MiB 

                                                                   
                                                                   


# rngd -v
Available entropy sources:
    Intel/AMD hardware rng
    DRNG
```

---

The above is a relatively new laptop (3.5 years old), having 7th gen of Intel CPU which is combined with the TPM 2.0 (however I do not know if `rngd` uses it by default). As you can see there is no error message produced, so I assume it is working well as it is without special settings. Note: the `DRNG` I do not know what that is.

---

```
root @ acer-5742g /root # neofetch 
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               root@acer-5742g 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           --------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: Aspire 5742G V1.24 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.15.0-57-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 36 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 2099 (dpkg), 8 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.1.16 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter (Muffin) 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM Theme: () 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Theme: Adwaita [GTK3] 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Icons: Adwaita [GTK3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Terminal: /dev/pts/0 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     CPU: Intel Pentium P6200 (2) @ 2.133GHz 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 520M 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: Intel Core Processor 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Memory: 689MiB / 3597MiB 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.                                       
                                                                   


root @ acer-5742g /root # rngd -v
read error

read error

Available entropy sources:
    Intel/AMD hardware rng
```

By contrast, the second computer above is many years old, and running `rngd` produces two errors, I mean:

> read error

Does this somehow affect the randomness `rngd` *delivers* to these old machines and do they need to adjust the `rngd` settings somehow, and if so, then how or what should I do?

Thanks.

Man page: https://linux.die.net/man/8/rngd

Note on DRNG:

> Digital Random Number Generator; it is an Intel hardware approach to high-quality, high-performance entropy and random number generation using the RDRAND processor instruction. Check with:

```
grep -m1 rdrand /proc/cpuinfo
```

---

```
systemctl status rngd -l
```

on the old computer produces this:

```
○ rngd.service - Start entropy gathering daemon (rngd)
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rngd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2023-01-06 06:03:46 CET; 1h 19min ago
       Docs: man:rngd(8)
    Process: 619 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rngd -f (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 619 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 2ms

Jan 06 06:03:45 acer-5742g rngd[619]: read error
Jan 06 06:03:45 acer-5742g rngd[619]: read error
Jan 06 06:03:45 acer-5742g rngd[619]: read error
Jan 06 06:03:45 acer-5742g rngd[619]: read error
Jan 06 06:03:45 acer-5742g rngd[619]: read error
Jan 06 06:03:45 acer-5742g rngd[619]: read error
Jan 06 06:03:45 acer-5742g rngd[619]: read error
Jan 06 06:03:45 acer-5742g rngd[619]: read error
Jan 06 06:03:45 acer-5742g rngd[619]: No entropy sources working, exiting rngd
Jan 06 06:03:46 acer-5742g systemd[1]: rngd.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caution: This is a pseudo solution because you fill in the `/dev/random` device with data from the `/dev/urandom` device.

---

Edit this file with your favorite editor:

```
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/rngd.service
```

Replace:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rngd -f
```

With:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rngd -f -r /dev/urandom
```

After saving that file, run:

```
systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart rngd.service
```

Check if working afterward:

```
# systemctl status rngd -l
● rngd.service - Start entropy gathering daemon (rngd)
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rngd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-01-06 08:07:33 CET; 8s ago
       Docs: man:rngd(8)
   Main PID: 4757 (rngd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4173)
     Memory: 224.0K
        CPU: 2ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/rngd.service
             └─4757 /usr/sbin/rngd -f -r /dev/urandom

Jan 06 08:07:33 acer-5742g systemd[1]: Started Start entropy gathering daemon (rngd).
```